# How to flash firmware from XperiFirm? Can Newflasher save user data?

Tags: rom-flashing, sony-xperia, flashtool

My phone is stuck in a bootloop and I would like to try to fix it by flashing stock firmware. I used XperiFirm to download firmware. But then in Flashtool it won't load. I tried going to tools -> bundles -> fileset decrypt but it just doesn't load it.

I'm running Windows and noticed a part of Flashtool was detected as a trojan. I made an exception and reinstalled so this shouldn't be a problem.

I tried clicking on the XperiFirm button directly inside Flashtool, but it really quickly flashes and goes away without doing anything (nothing is even added to the log).

I looked into using [Newflasher](https://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/sony/progress-newflasher-xperia-command-line-t3619426) but am wondering if there's a way to save data? I would like to do a dirty flash.

Comment: have you tried [Androxyde](https://github.com/Androxyde/Flashtool/blob/master/README.md#flashtool) Flashtool?
 https://www.hardreset.info/devices/sony/sony-xperia-xz1-compact/faq/firmware-flash

Comment: @alecxs yes that is the one I mean. I'm unable to do step 3) simply nothing happens. I've tried already but is there an additional step, for example must the phone be connected in a certain mode for XperiFirm to work?

Comment: ask in support forum [Androxyde](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=920746) Flashtool

Comment: found following instructions: 1) Unzip FTF file, extract the system.sin
2) Dump system image from system.sin with Flashtool
-> Advanced-> SIN Editor 3) rename system.ext4 -> system.img

Comment: I got the stand alone [XperiFirm](https://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/sony/pc-xperifirm-xperia-firmware-downloader-t2834142) to work. How do I know which version of the firmware to [download](https://www.hardreset.info/media/resetinfo/2017/328/145bdf645a5947e593e8d8fb67ba314b/sony-xperia-xz1-compact.jpg)? I had Pie working so guess it's 47.2 but I don't know what the last 3 characters mean e.g. `47.2.A.11.228-R2C` or ` R7C` My country isn't listed under "Market" but I'm planning on going with a customized US or UK.

Comment: After running `grep version /system/build.prop` I get the result with first line `ro.semc.version.fs_revision=47.2.A.4.41` For some reason XperiFirm doesn't have this version, but I found a download to it from the [Sony website](https://developer.sony.com/file/download/open-source-archive-for-47-2-a-4-41-and-47-2-a-4-45/). The download comes in a `bz2` which contains `tar` which contains all the folders including `system`. I'm not sure how to flash these files in this format...

Comment: after rethinking just flash `47.2.A.11.228` (don't know meaning of `-R2C`) encryption doesn't matter anymore (because you already have unencrypted `data.ext4.win` on PC) also TWRP is always bootable from fastboot for emergency: *'fastboot boot twrp-3.3.1-0-lilac.img'*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115954/discussion-between-jondon-and-alecxs).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the XperiFirm integrated into Flashtool to work. Even with the [stand alone](https://xperifirm.com/), it didn't have the firmware I was looking for. I ended up just Google searching the the firmware with "ftf". Flashing it with Flashtools worked fine.

TL;DR download the desired firmware as an FTF found through a Google Search. Flash it with Flashtool.